# Flaticon , position the ::before element

Tags: html, css

I'm using a font created with [flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com/)

My problem is that I can't place the icon vertically in a div

I've tried everything, vertical-align: middle, change the position: absolute / relative, margin, padding, line-height = height of the div ,  everything!

[image]

### flaticon css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("font/flaticon.eot");
    src: url("font/flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("font/flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
    url("font/flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("font/flaticon.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
    font-family: Flaticon;
font-style: normal;
}

.flaticon-synchronization1:before {
    content: "\e01e";
}
```

### my css

```
    body{
        background-color: gray;
    }

    #btnTest{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #btnTest > span{

        border: 1px solid red;

    }

    #btnTest > span::before{

        font-size: 30px;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid yellow;

    }
```

### html

```
<div id="btnTest"><span class="flaticon-synchronization1"></span></div>
```

### UPDATE , SOLUTION

```
    #btnTest{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: table;
    }

    #btnTest > span{

        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;

    }

    #btnTest > span::before{

        font-size: 30px;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid yellow;

    }
```

Comment: Add `line-height: 100px;` to `#btnTest > span::before`

Comment: I opened your example in Chrome console just to try it out and set the position of the "span::before" element to relative and I could change the position with adjusting the "top" value. Is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: Funny thing, in my browser it looks nothing like your image. In fact, it is perfectly centered.

Comment: @ Mary Melody , line-height, I know it works, but i don't know the height of my div. and therefore I should use something like this line-height = height of the div, but i can not do with the css ..

Comment: Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/rv264cww/

Comment: @Mary Melody , your solution works !

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could use `line-height` like this:

```
#btnTest > span::before{
   line-height:100px; // Equal the height of the parent
}
```

Now if you don't know the height of the parent try this:

```
#btnTest > span::after {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: line-height, I know it works, but i don't know the height of my div. and therefore I should use something like this line-height = height of the div, but i can not do with the css

Comment: @WhiteLine check the complement of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution is to make icon's `position:absolute`. Now `top` and `left` should both be `50%`, but now icon's top-left corner  is at button's center, so add `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` to make them co-centeric.

Make parent i.e. `#buttonTest` `position:relative`.

By this we can place icon at any position like `left: 75%, top:50%`.

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

#btnTest {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative
}

#btnTest>span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

#btnTest>span::before {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("font/flaticon.eot");
  src: url("font/flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("font/flaticon.woff") format("woff"), url("font/flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"), url("font/flaticon.svg") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="flaticon-"]:before,
[class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after,
[class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
  font-family: Flaticon;
  font-style: normal;
}

.flaticon-synchronization1:before {
  content: "\e01e";
}
```

```html
<div id="btnTest"><span class="flaticon-synchronization1"></span></div>
```